# Mysql Trigger not updating joined table

Tags: mysql, triggers

For some reason this trigger is not updating the Order table, what might I be doing incorrectly?

```
DELIMITER $$

/*!50003 DROP TRIGGER*//*!50032 IF EXISTS */ /*!50003 `orderTotalInsert` */$$

/*!50003 CREATE */ /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */ /*!50003 TRIGGER `orderTotalInsert` 
    AFTER INSERT ON `orderitem` FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
     UPDATE `Order`
    INNER JOIN (
        select orderitemID, SUM(orderitem.UnitPrice) sum_price
        from orderitem 
        group by orderitemID
    )  t on t.orderitemID = order.OrderId 
    SET  Order.TotalAmmount = t.sum_price;
    END */$$


DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Did you really spell `Order.TotalAmmount` with two M's?

Comment: oh man, yes i did :/, thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select orderitemID, SUM(orderitem.UnitPrice) sum_price
from orderitem 
group by orderitemID
```

This groups by `orderitemID`, which I'd guess is the primary key of the `orderitem` table. Because you're grouping by a unique column, the "groups" are always groups of 1, and the "sum" is always equal to each individual unitprice value.

The effect is that your UPDATE overwrites the `TotalAmmount` multiple times, and gets the last unitprice instead of the sum of all unitprices for the order.

You should be grouping by the `orderID`, so you get the total for all orderitems belonging to the same order.

```
select orderID, SUM(orderitem.UnitPrice) sum_price
from orderitem 
group by orderID
```

Second issue: You don't need to update *all* orders every time you insert an orderitem. You just need to update the total for one order, for the orderitem you're inserting. So you should just restrict the subquery to rows `WHERE orderID = NEW.orderID`.

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' TRIGGER `orderTotalInsert` 
AFTER INSERT ON `orderitem` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 UPDATE `Order`
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT orderID, SUM(orderitem.UnitPrice) sum_price
    FROM orderitem
    WHERE orderID = NEW.orderID
    GROUP BY orderID
 )  t on t.orderID = order.OrderId 
 SET Order.TotalAmmount = t.sum_price;
END
```

Comment: Thanks bill! this one did it. I did have to pull the extra M out of everything but seems to be functioning properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is `t.orderitemId = order.OrderId` really the right comparison? It seems like the subquery would be grouping on an `orderid` of its own, that references `Order`.

Alternatively, if my assumptions were right and there are similar UPDATE and DELETE triggers, you could simplify and reduce the cost of this trigger by using this update query instead.

```
UPDATE `Order` SET TotalAmmount = TotalAmmount + NEW.UnitPrice WHERE OrderId = NEW.OrderId;
```

for the UPDATE TRIGGER would be `SET TotalAmmount = TotalAmmount + NEW.UnitPrice - OLD.UnitPrice`

for the DELETE TRIGGER would be `SET TotalAmmount = TotalAmmount - OLD.UnitPrice`